# Serialized XML to JSON Angular Ionic

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I work in A web service that use serialized XML

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
<script/>
[{"id":1,"nameEn":"Riyadh"},{"id":4,"nameEn":"Jeddah"},{"id":5,"nameEn":"Alkhobar"},{"id":6,"nameEn":"Dammam"},{"id":7,"nameEn":"Mecca"},{"id":8,"nameEn":"Almadina"},{"id":9"nameEn":"Yanbu"}] </string>
```

I used this code to get data

```
getCities():Observable<any>{
    let parseResult:any;
   return this.http.get(this.myURL) 
    .map(res =>{
      try{
      return parseResult =  JSON.parse(res.json());
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log('error in parsing res.json');
      }
    });
```

the problem is some times res.json() work fine. another time the server replay with answer like `"[{\"id\":1,\"nameEn\":\"Riyadh\"},{\"id\":4,\"nameEn\":\"Jeddah\"}]"`
and It can't be parsed to JSON I have no idea why the response has slashes like this any help please

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. That's XML with some JSON in the content of an element. `JSON.parse` should always fail to parse such a response body.

Comment: Ok, but how can I get The Array from this @AluanHaddad

Comment: Parse the response as XML, access the content of the `<string>` element, and finally call `JSON.parse` on that content.

Comment: Any idea of how to do that or what should I use.

Comment: what gonna me crazy is used the same code and gives me right result [{"id":1,"nameEn":"Riyadh"},{"id":4,"nameEn":"Jeddah"},{"id":5,"nameEn":"Alkhobar"},{"id":6,"nameEn":"Dammam"},{"id":7,"nameEn":"Mecca"},{"id":8,"nameEn":"Almadina"},{"id":9"nameEn":"Yanbu"}] . and some times gives me [{\"id\":1,\"nameEn\":\"Riyadh\"},{\"id\":4,\"nameEn\":\"Jeddah\"}]. is it server issue or what is this mess .

Comment: You should log your inputs and make sure they're actually the same. If the server is returning results in an inconsistent format there's not much you can do. I suppose you could try to infer the format but that could get ugly

Comment: I used postman to see web service output. it gave me different  result 1- empty response 2- [{\"id\":1,\"nameEn\":\"Riyadh\"},{\"id\":4,\"nameEn\":\"Jed‌​dah\"}]. 3- [{"id":1,"nameEn":"Riyadh"},{"id":4,"nameEn":"Jeddah"},{"id"‌​:5,"nameEn":"Alkhoba‌​r"}].you are right,  the server is returning result in an inconsistent format. I informed the client about this issues to fix it .Thanks so much @AluanHaddad